# DDD/MVC Pure POCO classes can be presented directly to the View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture, domain-driven-design, dto

DDD/MVC describes keeping the damain entities and the View layers seperated, in order to keep the Views persistance ignorant and vice versa.  DTO's are a way of doing this.  I have looked at AutoMapper as a way to facilitate his.  However, since I have recently started with EF and pure POCO classes, is seems to me that a DTO, that directly maps a persistan ignorant POCO is really just a duplicate layer that servs no purpose at all other than to be able to say you are using DTO's.  What would be wrong with just simply skipping the DTO layer if your POCO is pure and persistance ignorant?

Thanks

JAMES

Answer (score 1):

One thing you have to keep in mind is about the model binder. It will bind any posted field that your model has a property with the same name.

To clarify this problem, imagine you are using a user model like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string login {get; set; }
    ...
    public bool admin { get; set; }
}
```

If you use this model on the signup page, even if you haven't created a field for the admin and setted scaffold to false, and a malicious user can create a form field called admin and set it to true (like a checkbox) on your page. Posting this form will cause your received model to have this property setted to true, making the user an admin.

This is why you have to use anti forgery tokens and view models to this cases aleviate the work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to have DTO (or ViewModels) is that the domain object is different than view.

For each View you should have a separate ViewModel that fits it. I can contain only data and metadata, like validation attributes.

Domain objects should not expose data but behavior that represents busiess rules.

If your View Models are just duplicating the Domain Models. If your Domain Models don't have any methods but only public properties. If you haven't defined ubiquitous language, aggregates, invariants... Then you're just not doing DDD but CRUD app. And in that case, indeed, DTO might be pointless.